# git subprojects with the same name as the upper projects

Tags: git

I have a git repository for my `home` folder (I call it `origin`). Inside my `home` folder i have the `workspace/` folder an inside some projects.

I have tried to create another repository for one of my projects using this:

```
$ git remote add origin ssh://tirengarfio@173.223.56.251/home/tirengarfio/git/my_project
```

but i get:

> fatal: remote origin already exists.

That's because as I already said I'm using a remote called origin for my `home` folder...

I know I could use another name, but I'm curious about how to use again the word `origin` for my_project repository.. Or should I just use another name?? What is your advice?

Comment: have you tried using a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git remote` doesn't create a repository. To create a new repository you need to use either `git init` or `git clone`.

I suspect you want to do:

```
cd ~/workspace
git clone ssh://tirengarfio@173.223.56.251/home/tirengarfio/git/my_project
```

This would create a new repository at `~/workspace/my_project` that is a clone of that URL. The new repository would already be setup with a remote named `origin` pointing at the URL from which the clone was made.

Comment: well, i maybe didn't use the right words, all this terms are not easy..:), but anyway, no, i dont want to clone. I created a remote repository in a remote host to push then my local contents to it. I'm following this: http://minimaldesign.net/articles/read/git-workflow-for-web-development

Comment: If you really are trying to just add a new remote to the existing repository, then no you can't use a name that is already used for a remote.

Comment: Did you do the `git init` portion of that article?

Comment: Then that's your problem. Doing that would create a new repository which would start with no remotes, so a new one named `origin` could be added. As it is you're working in the existing repository for your home folder which already has a remote with that name.

Comment: do you think i should modify the title or the content to make the question more correct?